# dynamically specifying variable name in a function

Tags: python, django

I am making a custom django template tag.

The rudimentary version:

```
import models

@register.filter
def intensity1(value):
    return models.CHOICES_FOO[value]
```

It just returns the value'th element of `model.FOO` list

But I actually have a few different lists,  `models.CHOICES_BAR`, `models.CHOICES_BAZ`

So I thought to make a more generalized function, pass it the `value` and an `arg` which specifies which variable list to refer to.

```
@register.filter
def intensity2(value, arg):
    return models.arg[value]


arg = "INTENSITY_CHOICES"
print (intensity2(value, arg))
```

But of course this doesn't work.  Failing with `module 'models' has no attribute 'arg'`

Is there a way to state something like that? or would I be better off keeping all these choices in a `dict` and then retrieve them by referring to the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `getattr` to get a property by name:

```
return getattr(models, arg)[value]
```

Comment: A `dict` of choices is probably how I'd go, but this is how you solve the general problem of accessing an item by name.